# Function pointers as entry points for any device operations

Tags: c, unix, linux-device-driver

```
/* angus - Simple program to open,release,read,write */
#include<linux/fs.h>
#include<linux/uaccess.h>
#include<linux/slab.h>
#include<linux/gfp.h>

char *my_buff;
int major = -1;

int my_open(struct inode *inodes, struct file *files);
int my_release(struct inode *inodes, struct file *files);
ssize_t my_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *ppos);
ssize_t my_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *ppos);

static const struct file_operations fops = {
        .open = my_open,
        .release = my_release,
        .read = my_read,
        .write = my_write
};


int init_module(void){
        printk("Hi Angus \n");
        major = register_chrdev(0,"hello",&fops);
        printk("Major no : %d \n",major);
        return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void){
        kfree(my_buff);
        unregister_chrdev(major,"hello");
        printk("Bye Angus \n");
}

int my_open(struct inode *inodes, struct file *files){
        printk("my_open Angus \n");
        return 0;
}

int my_release(struct inode *inodes, struct file *files){
        printk("my_release Angus \n");
        return 0;
}

ssize_t my_read(struct file *file, char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *ppos){
        if(copy_to_user(buf,my_buff,len)){ // On success returns 0 and failure returns no of bytes not copied
                return -1;
        }
        printk("my_read Angus \n");
        return len;
}

ssize_t my_write(struct file *file, const char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *ppos){
        ssize_t size = len;
        my_buff = kmalloc(100,GFP_KERNEL);
        if(copy_from_user(my_buff,buf,len)){
                return -1;
        }
        printk("my_write Angus \n");
        return size;
}

/* Output */

/* Step : 1 
[ 9079.100187] Hi Angus 
[ 9079.100193] Major no : 250 
[ 9081.321078] my_open Angus 
[ 9081.321157] my_read Angus 
[ 9081.321170] my_write Angus 
[ 9081.321206] my_release Angus 
[ 9131.037905] Bye Angus 
*/

/*Step : 2
mknod hello c 250 0
$cat /proc/devices
*/
```

I tried the above program to understand the read, write entry points that happens at the driver level.

1. But I couldn't get from where the read() function pointer with which I'm registering my_read is getting called.
2. Why does the entry points are always written using function pointers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are callng `register_chrdev` in your `init_module` function. This passes the structure `fops` of function pointers to the kernel. One of the fields of `fops` is `read` which you initialized to `my_read`.
2. Because it is a clean mechanism for indirection of functionality, the equivalent of a C++ virtual table. How else is the kernel to communicate with your device driver to ask it to read/ write? The kernel could pass a function code (0 = read , 1 = write) but the function pointer mechanism is more direct. Since most devices are expected to support open, read, and write, it's more direct and less code to implement them as function pointers. Having said that, the `ioctl` allows you to send function codes to the device driver, but this is normally best avoided unless the operation your device driver implemenents can't be modeled well as a open, read, write, etc.